# How is this JavaScript function caching its results?

Tags: javascript, caching, hash, memoization

After reading over it several times, I still don't understand how this example code from page 76 of [Stoyan Stefanov's "JavaScript Patterns"](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596806767/) works. I'm not a ninja yet. But to me, it reads like it's only storing an empty object:

```
var myFunc = function (param) {
  if (!myFunc.cache[param]) {
    var result = {};
    // ... expensive operation ...
    myFunc.cache[param] = result;
  } 
  return myFunc.cache[param];
};
// cache storage
myFunc.cache = {};
```

Unless that unseen "expensive operation" is storing back to `result`, I don't see anything being retained.

Where are the results being stored?

P.S.: I've read [Caching the return results of a function from John Resig's Learning Advanced JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333914/caching-the-return-results-of-a-function-from-john-resigs-learning-advanced-java), which is a similar exercise, and I get that one. But the code is different here.

Comment: The "expensive operation" is populating the `result` object which is then stored under the `param` name inside the `cache` property of the `myFunc` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've answered your own question -- the author assumes that the expensive operation will store its result in `result`.

The cache would otherwise only contain empty objects, as you've noted.

Comment: Hmm... I suspected. In other examples, he's been great about explaining what happens in parts of the code that are important to the exercise, even if they're abstracted for clarity. So this one threw me... But I also thought it might've been over my head and worth asking about.

Answer (score 2):

the results are being stored in the object literal called 'cache'.  What the code is specifically doing is:

when myFunc gets executed with a param, the function first checks the cache.  If there is a value for 'param' in the cache, it returns it.  If not, you do the expensive operation, and then cache the result(with param as the key), so the next time the function is called with the same param the cache is used.

Answer (score 1):

It says // expensive operation - the inference is that you implement code there which assigns variables into the result var, or sets the result var to another Object (which is the result of an expensive operation)