# is Memoization and Cache function execution in javascript are same?

Tags: javascript, memoization

I recently had an interview where I was asked that how could you **cache execution of any function**? I heard about **Functional Caching in Javascript** only.

I checked on [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090391/how-is-this-javascript-function-caching-its-results) but not getting any idea from this.Is Memorization and Cache function execution is same or different thing?

I know *Functional Caching in Javascript* called **Memoization** that cache the result only not execution but what about **Cache function execution?**.

Comment: Are you talking about memoization?

Comment: Read here: https://coderwall.com/p/tyy7lw/function-caching-in-javascript-caching-catching

Comment: I think no.Functional Caching in Javascript call  memoization https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090391/how-is-this-javascript-function-caching-its-results

Comment: OK, now I'm confused. I added the `memoization` tag because I thought that's what you were talking about, but now you're saying "no". Can you clarify?

Comment: @melpomene I think memoization is just caching the result of function not execution.sorry if I m wrong

Comment: Maybe what you've read and what the interviewer talked about is actually the same thing, but as you both didn't know the correct term for this (memoization) you were confused?

Comment: If you cache the result of a function you won't call it again, so you kind of "cache the execution"

Comment: @JonasW. I believe both are different things as interviewer mentioned not about memorization

Comment: "cache the execution" for me seems something related to js's JIT optimization strategies; almost sure that's not what they were asking you. I think they were talking about memoization as well.

Comment: I'm sorry but without the exact wording of your interviewer its not possible to answer what he was asking for.

Comment: @JonasW.- sorry I already told you it was **cache execution of any function**

Comment: I guess it's only memoization(caching the results corresponding to set of input params) to achieve efficiency. What would caching an execution after all mean or serve for that sake?

Comment: @JonasW. I found something on net-You could have a method where you will pass a function and it will internally maintain a cache object where calculated value will be cached. When you will call the function with same argument, the cached value will be served.does it make sense?

Comment: Thats memoization

Comment: @JonasW. but then why 2 questions here 17 and 18 https://www.thatjsdude.com/interview/js2.html#currying ?sorry for trouble

Comment: They once used the term memoization and once they used another term to describe the same thing

Comment: Thats still memoization. The "Cache function execution" that you are referring to is still using the same concept of memoization, with the difference that you have a factory function that you can reuse. Basically, a cache decorator. You don't add caching directly in your main function ( like in example 17 ), but, through composition, you can add memoization to your function. And the original function is not aware about memoization at all, @NullPointer. For example, you can have a normal "fibonacci" function, with no caching, and a `const fibonacciWithCaching = cacheFn(fibonacci)` with caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's still memoization, in the way of optimization strategies there is no difference between the both in term of the cached data but in the way of use.

Usual memorization will remember (cache) the results (used in the *expensive* function calls) and return the cached result when the same inputs occur again.

The "Cache Function Execution" use the same concept by storing in memory, but this time storing the function body itself instead of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, usually, it is the same thing.

There are multiple ways to implement it, but the idea remains the same - avoiding extra calculations of the function. It is also language agnostic thing.

One condition the function should meet is **purity** (e.g. no side effects and referential transparency - same input gives the same output). It's not a functional programming thing, but in FP functions are pure most of the time.

So, if the function is pure the callee should not notice any difference if instead of executing a function body we immediately return the cached value.
In other words, if the function is **pure** then there is **no real difference** between memoization and so-called *cache function execution* since return value will be the same.

---

**What if the function is not pure?**

Well, in this case, obviously, if we skip the function body and immediately return a cached value - we will miss the function side effect. Optimizing such function would lead us to a separation of pure and impure stuff, and the good now we know how to deal with the first one :)